# Improving this Generic Request Response Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Lately I seem to be working with lots of request/response stuff and I thought of creating something generic.

I have the following but I am not happy about creating multiple ifs statements and I would like to avoid them.

The idea is this:

Regardless of the request /response process them.
How can I remove these if statement within my generic request Handler?

Code

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        IRequestResponseFactory factory = new RequestResponseFactory();

        var customerRequest = new CustomerRequest { Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs" };
        var customerResponse = factory.ProcessRequest<CustomerRequest, CustomerResponse>(customerRequest);

        var billRequest = new BillRequest() { Amount = 100m };
        var billResponse = factory.ProcessRequest<BillRequest, BillResponse>(billRequest);

        Console.WriteLine(billResponse.Success);
        Console.WriteLine(customerResponse.Success);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}


public class CustomerRequest : IRequestData<CustomerResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
public class BillRequest : IRequestData<BillResponse>
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
public class BillResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
public interface IRequestData<TResponse>
{
}

public interface IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IRequestData<TResponse>
{
    TResponse ProcessRequest(TRequest request);
}

public interface IRequestResponseFactory
{
    TResponse ProcessRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IRequestData<TResponse>;
}
class RequestResponseFactory : IRequestResponseFactory
{
    public TResponse ProcessRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IRequestData<TResponse>
    {
        var handler = new GenericRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>();
        TResponse response = handler.ProcessRequest(request);
        return response;
    }
}
public class GenericRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IRequestData<TResponse>
{
    public TResponse ProcessRequest(TRequest request)
    {
        var response = default(TResponse);

        //How do I avoid this if statements????

        if (request is IRequestData<CustomerResponse>)
        {
            var tempResponse = new CustomerResponse { Success = true };
            response = (TResponse)Convert.ChangeType(tempResponse, typeof(TResponse));
            return response;
        }
        if (request is IRequestData<BillResponse>)
        {
            var tempResponse = new BillResponse { Success = false };
            response = (TResponse)Convert.ChangeType(tempResponse, typeof(TResponse));
            return response;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace the `GenericRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>` class with specialized `IRequestHandler`s and have the factory keep track of all available such handlers via reflection.

Concretely, these could be the handlers:

```
public class CustomerRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<CustomerRequest, CustomerResponse>
{
    public CustomerResponse ProcessRequest(CustomerRequest request)
    {
        return new CustomerResponse { Success = true };
    }
}

public class BillRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<BillRequest, BillResponse>
{
    public BillResponse ProcessRequest(BillRequest request)
    {
        return new BillResponse { Success = false };
    }
}
```

Now, the factory, instead of just forwarding the call to the generic handler that contains the `if` ugliness, will do the following:

- initialize itself by scanning the current assembly (and possibly other assemblies as well) for types that implement `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>`
- will build a dictionary of handler types, where the key is the `TRequest` type and the value is the handler type
- on any incoming request it checks the handler list to see if that particular type can be handled and:

  - delegates the work to the available handler
  - throws an exception if no suitable handler is found

This is a possible implementation for the factory class:

```
class RequestResponseFactory : IRequestResponseFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _requestHandlerTypes;

    public RequestResponseFactory()
    {
        _requestHandlerTypes =
            typeof(RequestResponseFactory).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
                .Select(t => new
                {
                    HandlerType = t,
                    RequestType = GetHandledRequestType(t)
                })
                .Where(x => x.RequestType != null)
                .ToDictionary(
                    x => x.RequestType,
                    x => x.HandlerType
                );
    }

    private static Type GetHandledRequestType(Type type)
    {
        var handlerInterface = type.GetInterfaces()
            .FirstOrDefault(i =>
                i.IsGenericType &&
                i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));

        return handlerInterface == null ? null : handlerInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

    public TResponse ProcessRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IRequestData<TResponse>
    {
        if (!_requestHandlerTypes.ContainsKey(typeof(TRequest)))
            throw new ApplicationException("No handler registered for type: " + typeof(TRequest).FullName);

        var handlerType = _requestHandlerTypes[typeof(TRequest)];

        var handler = (IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>)Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);

        return handler.ProcessRequest(request);
    }
}
```

**The complete program with working sample is available at http://ideone.com/TxRnEi.**

The output is the same as the output of the original program, but now the program allows you to add new types of requests and new types of handlers and will be able to dynamically use them at run time, without you having to write the long `if`/`case` statements to specify when they should be used.

Comment: Hi,that definetely works. I guess reflection is necessary to avoid if statements.Thanks!

Comment: @user231465 Yes, it's a possible solution. One word of caution though: reflection is known to be slow. If you have to run these operations with a very high frequency (ex: thousands of times a second) this may pose a performance problem.

Comment: @wOlf your input is great.Are you saying that if I want a fast performing factory I have no option but if statement to avoid reflection.I guess using something like Unity would not do any good either.How would you do if it was you?

Comment: @user231465 That depends on many factors. If I had a relatively low number of request types and no resemblance in the way they are handled I'd probably expose a number of `HandleFooRequest` methods (for example WCF operation contracts) and provide no other abstraction over it.